# Store a lot of object properties

Tags: php, forms, class, oop, architecture

I'm learning OOP PHP and have a little problem concerning classes design.

I have a User class, that will contain basics users fields (mail, personnal infos, etc...)

And some child class for custom user types (user, admin, client...).

These child class have a "formFields" property. It's an array that contain all the fields needed for a form.

Example :

```
 array('user_mail' => array('label' => 'E-mail', 
                            'name' => 'user[user_mail]', 
                            'required' => 1), 
       'js' => 'some custom script', 
       classes => 'css classes', 
       etc...);
```

There will be a lot of forms, and a lot of fields according to the child class type...

I'm not sure about the best way to go.

Store these fields in object is simple at the beginning, but it's begins to be hard to maintain.
(And each time i do a var_dump I get a page filled with the same properties...)

I don't think that making a database table for each form is a good idea, because of the form multiple versions.

I could make a single database for all the fields from all the forms, but a lot of table fields will not be used... (Or serialize them ? isn't this a bit strange ?)

I don't see a lot of solutions, maybe someone know what is the best...

TL/DR :

Best way to store multiple form fields ?

- Array as object property
- Multiple tables
- One big table
- XML
- Text file or something...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract these fields to some sort of form class managing them. Based on the requesting object (e.g. User or Admin etc) it returns a different set of forms.

In its cleanest way if you want to do OOP, you create a factory (factory pattern) and return a new Form object with the correct fields you can use to construct the form. Make all these items of an interface called `IFormObject` or similar and provide access to these functions.

Rough way, just make one form object and encapsulate the logic in there and just populate the form data based on the requesting object (User, Admin etc.)

Comment: Ok, so i should store everything into properties ? The idea of sending the result based on the requesting object is good, but do you know a function to know what  is the object calling the method ? And, last but not least, I don't understand the point of using interfaces. Thanks for your ideas, and thanks if you have time to explain a bit more.

Comment: In PHP to detect what object is calling the method you can use the 'instanceof' operator. In pure OOP this is not ideal because you create a hard dependency, but in your code it is not much of a problem. The interfaces are there to make your resulting object "polymorph" so that no matter what object is returned, your consuming class always knows  how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand your problem correctly, I would rather do the opposite.
I mean, I would have create a bunch of different users (Admin,User,Client,etc) with restricted set of properties combine with inherited properties from the parent class, and a limited amount of special properties specific to the category.

Then, I would create each one of my objects and view with a specific flag on Database regarding the access level required to read/write or execute it (On web it would be screen it on edit mode, read only mode or not at all).

I now that it's maybe not the answer that you were waiting for, but its my way to do a more flexible and maintainable application.